# Interrelate select options with an array items

Tags: javascript

How do I interrelate the `select` options with an `array` items and change content on button click?

I want to chage the content of a div dynamically using the select option and a button. The words I want to display are sotred in an array.

Here is my code:

```js
function myCall() {
  var dBox = document.getElementById('displayBox');
  var msg = ["Good", "Fine", "Helpful", "Fantastic"];
  dBox.innerHTML = `${msg[2]}!`;
}
```

```css
#displyBox {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00d500;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="displayBox">Change Words!</div>
<select>
  <option>Good</option>
  <option>Fine</option>
  <option selected>Helpful</option>
  <option>Fantastic</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="myCall()">Change Word</button>
```

Comment: PS... don't use `onclick` same as you hopefully don't use `style`

Comment: `displyBox` what means `disply`?

Comment: It should be: displayBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the `"change"` Event directly on your Select box
- Don't use HTML inline `on*` handlers. JS and CSS should be in their respective tags / files.

```js
const EL_box = document.querySelector("#box");
const EL_words = document.querySelector("#words");

const populateBox = () => {
  EL_box.innerHTML = EL_words.value;
};

EL_words.addEventListener("change", populateBox); // on change
populateBox();                                    // on init
```

```css
#box {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00d500;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Change Words</div>
<select id="words">
  <option>Good</option>
  <option>Fine</option>
  <option selected>Helpful</option>
  <option>Fantastic</option>
</select>
```

If you really need a button:

```js
const EL_box = document.querySelector("#box");
const EL_words = document.querySelector("#words");
const EL_change = document.querySelector("#change");

const populateBox = () => {
  EL_box.innerHTML = EL_words.value;
};

EL_change.addEventListener("click", populateBox); // on click
populateBox();                                    // on init
```

```css
#box {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00d500;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Change Words</div>
<select id="words">
  <option>Good</option>
  <option>Fine</option>
  <option selected>Helpful</option>
  <option>Fantastic</option>
</select>

<button id="change" type="button">CHANGE</button>
```

Comment: It's great, but the question specifically asked "on button click", "dynamically using the select option and a button". Not combining `<select>` change event with `<div>` value change without any other interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example:

First, it will be important to use value property with the the  tag, like:

```
<div id="displyBox">Change Words!</div>

 <select id="selectbox">
  <option value="Good">Good</option>
  <option value="Fine">Fine</option>
  <option value="Helpful" selected>Helpful</option>
  <option value="Fantastic">Fantastic</option>
</select>
  
<button type="button" id="buttonChange">Change Word</button>
```

i prefer use addEventListener instead of "onclick" attribute. it divides your view and business logic layers, that makes code more dry and clear :)

then, take a look at js:

```
const displyBox = document.getElementById('displyBox')

const buttonChange = document.getElementById('buttonChange')

const selectbox = document.getElementById('selectbox')

buttonChange.addEventListener('click', () => {
  displyBox.innerHTML=selectbox.value
})
```

link every important html-node to js constant. add eventListener to your html-button node and pass callback function inside. Callback function changes innerHTML property tag you need by the actual selectbox value.

Here is working example at codepen:
https://codepen.io/zaslavskij/pen/mdWPMRg

Comment: Useful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an id to your select like this...

```js
function myCall() {
    var dBox = document.getElementById('displyBox');
    var msg = ["Good", "Fine", "Helpful", "Fantastic"];
    dBox.innerHTML = `${msg[document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex]}!`;
}
```

```css
#displyBox {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #00d500;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="displyBox">Change Words!</div>
<select id = "select">
<option>Good</option>
<option>Fine</option>
<option>Helpful</option>
<option>Fantastic</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="myCall()">Change Word</button>
```

Comment: It's useful too.

Answer (score -1):

- You need to add value to your options like `<option value=0>Good</option>`
- Then you need to get value from `<select>` to change on button click.
  check following code like `document.getElementById('vals').value`
- Based on that value you need to select the index of the element from word list array like `${msg[selectedVal]}`

```js
function myCall() {
var dBox = document.getElementById('displyBox');
let selectedVal = document.getElementById('vals').value
var msg = ["Good", "Fine", "Helpful", "Fantastic"];
dBox.innerHTML = `${msg[selectedVal]}!`;
}
```

```html
<div id="displyBox">Change Words!</div>
<select id="vals">
<option value=0>Good</option>
<option value=1>Fine</option>
<option selected  value=2>Helpful</option>
<option  value=3>Fantastic</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="myCall()">Change Word</button>
```